# Run part of a chunk in Quarto

Tags: r, quarto

I was wondering if it is possible to run a part of a code chunk without commenting the lines we don't want to run. For example we have the following qmd file:

````
---
title: "Run only part of code chunk without commenting"
---

```{r}
data(trees)
head(trees)

plot(Girth ~ Height, data = trees, pch=16)
mod <- lm(Girth ~ Height, data = trees)

summary(mod)
```
````

Imagine we only want to run the line 6 until line 9, how could we do this? I don't want to use comments like this:

````
---
title: "Run only part of code chunk without commenting"
---

```{r}
data(trees)
head(trees)

plot(Girth ~ Height, data = trees, pch=16)
#mod <- lm(Girth ~ Height, data = trees)

#summary(mod)
```
````

The main reason for this is that I want to show the complete code but not run all code. When we comment on some lines, it doesn't look great. So I was wondering if anyone knows if this is possible in `Quarto`?

Comment: Have you considered "```{r, eval=FALSE}" ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `eval = 1:4` to select lines of code that will be run, but it comments them out automatically. You can also use `#| eval: !expr 1:4` to make it more Quarto-y.

````
---
title: "Run only part of code chunk without commenting"
---

```{r, eval = 1:4}
data(trees)
head(trees)

plot(Girth ~ Height, data = trees, pch=16)
mod <- lm(Girth ~ Height, data = trees)

summary(mod)
```
````

[image]

Comment: Really useful answer. Thank you @Maël!!!  Checking out the documentation [here](https://quarto.org/docs/reference/cells/cells-knitr.html#code-output) also you can use `#| eval: [1, 2, 3, 4]` but definitely `#| eval: !expr 1:4` is more general.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question, a rather cumbersome workaround to avoid comments would be to first show all code but do not evaluate it, and then only run the code you want but do not show it, e.g.

````
```{r}
#| eval: false
#| echo: true
data(trees)
head(trees)

plot(Girth ~ Height, data = trees, pch=16)
mod <- lm(Girth ~ Height, data = trees)

summary(mod)
```


```{r}
#| echo: false
data(trees)
head(trees)

plot(Girth ~ Height, data = trees, pch=16)
```
````